# Can some please help me in this step? Differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

​"I can't understand how they differentiated from step $(1)$ to step $(2)$"

> So wave function is:
> $$ \varphi_v(x)=\left(\frac{1}{2\alpha(\pi)^{1/2}}\right)^{1/2}(2y)e^{-y^2/2}$$
> To finally calculate value of most probable displacement
> \begin{align}
> \frac{d\varphi}{dx} &= 0 \\
> \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{2\alpha(\pi)^{1/2}}\right)^{1/2}(2y)e^{-y^2/2} &= 0 \\
> \left(\frac{1}{2\alpha(\pi)^{1/2}}\right)^{1/2}(2)\frac{d}{dx}(y)e^{-y^2/2} &= 0 \tag{1}\\
> \left(\frac{1}{2\alpha(\pi)^{1/2}}\right)^{1/2}e^{-y^2/2}(1-y^2) &=0 \tag{2}\\
> \end{align}
> So:
> \begin{align}
> (1-y^2) &=0 \\
> y^2 &= 1 \\
> \left(\frac {x}{\alpha}\right) &= 1\\
> x &= \pm \alpha
> \end{align}

[My question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmTpI.png)

[Edited Full question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuQ7K.png)

Comment: Could you please provide a little bit more context. The notation used doesn't really sem consistent. I am assuming that $y$ is a function of $x$ but as written in the attachment it is incorrect. You should also use mathjax to format math notation in your questions.

Comment: Use a title that is specific to the problem. "I can't understand how so and so.." I think that can be omitted. Otherwise you wouldn't be asking about it. Include your thoughts or attempts.

Comment: This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: They seem to have tried to derive a product, but then there should be a $y'$ somewhere, assuming $y$ is a function of $x$.

Comment: Its actually a quantum mechanics question, the mathematical step was what I was confused at. I edited it and included the full equations, maybe that might give a clearer view. Have a look and I will look into MathJax tutorials as well.

Comment: It is just the product rule of differentiation, followed by factoring out the exponential that the resulting two terms share. Assuming $y=x/\alpha$ then there is a factor $\alpha$ missing, though that does not make a difference to the answer since the derivative is being equated with $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have equation $(1)$
$$\left(\frac{1}{2\alpha(\pi)^{1/2}}\right)^{1/2}(2)\frac{d}{dx}(y)e^{-y^2/2} = 0$$
dividing both sides by $2$ we get,
$$\left(\frac{1}{2\alpha(\pi)^{1/2}}\right)^{1/2}\frac{d}{dx}(y)e^{-y^2/2} = 0 \tag{i}$$
Let us now focus on the $\frac{d}{dx}(y)e^{-y^2/2}$ part of the equation.
Note that the [product rule of differentiation](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-differentiation-1-new/ab-2-8/a/product-rule-review) states
$$\frac{d(uv)}{dx} = u\frac{dv}{dx}+v\frac{du}{dx} $$
Clearly we have $u = y$ and $v= e^{-y^2/2}$
Note that in the second to last step you have substituted $y=\frac{x}{\alpha}$, so I assume this to be true to solve this question further.
\begin{align}
\frac{d(ye^{-y^2/2})}{dx} &= y\frac{d(e^{-y^2/2})}{dx}+e^{-y^2/2}\frac{dy}{dx}\\
&= y\frac{d(e^{-x^2/2\alpha^2})}{dx}+e^{-y^2/2}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x}{\alpha}\right)\\
&=y\frac{-x(e^{-x^2/2\alpha^2})}{\alpha^2}+e^{-y^2/2}\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)\\
&= e^{-x^2/2\alpha^2}\left(\frac{-xy}{\alpha^2} + \frac{1}{\alpha} \right)\\
&= e^{-y^2/2}\left(\frac{-(y\alpha)y}{\alpha^2} + \frac{1}{\alpha} \right) \\
&= e^{-y^2/2}\left(\frac{-y^2}{\alpha} + \frac{1}{\alpha} \right)\\
&= e^{-y^2/2}\left(\frac{1-y^2}{\alpha}\right) \tag{ii}
\end{align}
Substituting $\text{(ii)}$ in $\text{(i)}$, we get:
$$\left(\frac{1}{2\alpha(\pi)^{1/2}}\right)^{1/2}e^{-y^2/2}\left(\frac{1-y^2}{\alpha}\right) = 0$$
Multiplying both sides by $\alpha$ we get,
$$\left(\frac{1}{2\alpha(\pi)^{1/2}}\right)^{1/2}e^{-y^2/2}\left(1-y^2\right) = 0$$
Which is the required equation $(2)$
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You have to differentiate $ ye^{\Large\frac{-y^{2}}{2}}$ where $y=f(x)$.

So $$ \frac d{dx}ye^{\Large\frac{-y^{2}}{2}}\\=\Big(f(x)e^{\Large\frac{-f^2(x)}{2}}\Big)'\\=f'(x)e^{\Large\frac{-f^2(x)}{2}}+f(x)e^{\Large\frac{-f^2(x)}{2}}\Big(\frac{-f^2(x)}{2}\Big)'=\\f'(x)e^{\Large\frac{-f^2(x)}{2}}-f'(x)f^2(x)e^{\Large\frac{-f^2(x)}{2}}=\\ f'(x)e^{\Large\frac{-f^2(x)}{2}}(1-f^2(x))=\\y'e^{\Large\frac{-y^{2}}{2}}(1-y^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

HINTS

As a first step we take a simplified normal distribution function and later build in needed constants to handle $x,y $ variables.

Finding points of inflection in Bell curve starting from its ODE:

Normalization coefficient set to unity.(Prime is derivate w.r.t $x$)

$$ y'= -xy \tag1$$

Integrate

$$ y = y_i e^{-(x^2/2)}\tag2 $$

Plug 2) into 1)

$$ y'= -2 ~x~ e^{-(x^2/2)}\tag 3$$

Derivate again

$$ y''= -2 (1-x^2) e^{-(x^2/2)}\tag 4$$

Inflection points are at $y''=0$ or

$$ x=\pm 1~, x=\pm \infty, \tag 5 $$

where the former are $~\pm 1\sigma $ probability limits in the pdf.